# AWS S3 Access Denied on python virtual environment

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, virtualenv

I want to write a csv file to an s3 bucket

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'test':[1,2,3,4]})
# write to s3
df.to_csv('s3://<my-bucket>/test.csv', index=False)
# read from s3
df_read = pd.read_csv('s3://<my-bucket>/test.csv')
```

I've installed s3fs and configured the awscli

This code works fine on a virtual environment installed before awscli
However new virtual environments have read-only permission

Can anyone help me understand how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if this is a standalone script you run in it in few ways:

1. Pass the credentials as environment variables like

if you are using windows

```
    set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="your_key_id"
    set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="your_secret_key"
    set AWS_REGION=<REGION_NAME>
```

Mac OSX/Linux

```
    $ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="your_key_id"
    $ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="your_secret_key"
    $ export AWS_REGION=<REGION_NAME>
```

2. Pass the profile name while running the script

   ```
   AWS_PROFILE=foo script.py
   ```
3. Create the client by specifying the profile

   ```
   dev = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=<MY_PROFILE_NAME>)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You **first** have to setup `aws cli` and **then** do `aws config` - after this you can easily use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI credentials and configuration settings take precedence over Instance profile credentials, so you need to configure cli to assume IAM role with write permission or grant the current AWS cli user credentials write permission.